# Do we need to replace HTML comments with ColdFusion comments?

Tags: html, regex, coldfusion, comments

ColdFusion comments have an extra dash - so:

```
<!--- Comment here --->
```

instead of plain html:

```
<!-- Comment here -->
```

We have a small section of the site that was set up with templates by a non-ColdFusion developer, and he used html comments instead of CF comments in all the template files. Is it a problem to leave them as plain html comments? (And if we should switch them all to cf comments - what regex find/replace can I use? :) )

Answer (score 10):

You need to understand what has been enclosed in HTML comments.

If an ColdFusion statement has been HTML commented it will still execute but a ColdFusion commented section will not. For example...

```
<!--<cfset message="Hi">-->
<cfoutput>#message#</cfoutput>
```

...will work and display in the browser and...

```
<!--<cfset message="Hi">-->
<!--<cfoutput>#message#</cfoutput>-->
```

...will work but not display in the browser but will in the HTML source but...

```
<!---<cfset message="Hi">--->
<cfoutput>#message#</cfoutput>
```

...will fail with "Variable MESSAGE is undefined".

Comment: Thanks. So if it's just comments explaining the code - e.g. "if user is already logged in, redirect" - is it safe to leave or can it possibly throw things off (because CF will try to execute it)?

Comment: It depends on what is in the comments to begin with. As Richard explained, if you have CF code in the HTML comment, it will be executed.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to have an explanation comment in the code that isn't displayed in the HTML source code. In which case a ColdFusion comment can be used. I sometimes put a link to a blog article that explains a technique I've used in a ColdFusion comment. That comment is viewable to the developer but not to someone looking at the HTML source of the site.

Comment: Keep in mind that while ColdFusion comments won't show in HTML source code, they can add whitespace (depending on ColdFusion whitespace handling settings).

Answer (score 2):

You should also consider replacing all of the standard straightforward HTML comments with CF comments. Those are stripped away at the server and as such they're not delivered to the client.

Removing them makes the page a touch lighter and drops your bandwidth bill every so slightly. Zap an extra thousand byes of comments on a million page views, and you just saved a gig of data...

Answer (score 1):

I would also replace them with CF comments. Aside from the page size and white space saving you could be exposing details of your app to clients. Comments may give away sensitive details of the app which may be used to exploit or manipulate it. Clients (or robots) don't need that info.